# What is the VB 6 equivalent of Process.Start?

Tags: process, vb6

I am stuck on a really stuck with this one line. In vb.net this is easy, but how do I do this in vb6? Tried to search from google for few hours and got nothing. Feels almost embrassing.

Here's the code. (.NET)

```
Process.Start("runme.exe", " -parameter1 " & "-parameter2 " & "-parameter3")
```

I want to run EXE, from the same directory as where the program is, with parameters. I am sure there is some very simple solution, but I can't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. While this question may be useful to you, it's not really useful to the wider community as it stands. Please rework the question or it risks being closed as too localised.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with the question itself, it just was in desperate need of a better title. I don't think it's too localized. I can imagine lots of people wanting to know how to launch an external process from VB 6.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `Shell` and `ShellExecute`

```
Shell "c:\runme.exe", vbNormalFocus
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242087(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: +1. With the arguments `Shell "c:\runme.exe -parameter1 -parameter2 -parameter3", vbNormalFocus)`

Answer (score 3):

Just call Shell, and the parameters should be passed also with the string of the .exe name, like this:

```
Call Shell("""runme.exe"" ""-parameter1 "" ""-parameter2""", vbNormalFocus)
```

PS: The quotes make the difference, dont ignore it :)

Comment: I had syntax error with this: Shell("""runme.exe"" ""-parameter1 "" ""-parameter2""", vbNormalFocus) :S

Comment: It's the parenthesis. When VB6 sees them it expects a return value. Either lose the parenthesis, or use the `Call` keyword, `Call Shell("""runme.exe"" ""-parameter1 "" ""-parameter2""", vbNormalFocus)`

Comment: You are right, i was a VB6 developer for a few years, but it has being a while so i forgot to use the Call , thanks :)

Comment: THe quotes in this example can also break the parsing. Normally, parameters themselves aren't quoted, while values are. They also make this reply, not a direct translation of the original.

Comment: You are wrong, in VB6 those parameters must have double quotes, so they are identified mot as a single parameter

Comment: @GabrielVonlantenC.Lopes how do you mean? VB6 only sees a single "command line string", both concatenated to the executable in `Shell()` or on the receiving end in `Command$()`. You need to split yourself in code on spaces (outside quotes). There is no application that expects the parameters themselves to be quoted.

Comment: If you take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe736fyk%28v=vs.71%29.aspx you will see what i mean. It is the correct use, because each pair of adjacent double quotes ("") within the string literal is interpreted as one double quote character in the string. Therefore, the example presents the correct approach. Please read what microsoft says: "You should always enclose the entire path and file specification in quotes"

Answer (score 0):

You can use ShellExecute for this:

```
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

ShellExecute 0, "open", App.Path & "\runme.exe", "-parameter1 -parameter2 -parameter3", vbNullString, vbNormalFocus
```

I have found that using Shell causes a delay in the calling program waiting for the return value, whereas ShellExecute does not.

Comment: I found the opposite: Shell is about 10 times faster than ShellExecute.