# VB6 Why this doesn't change? [Checkbox & Textbox]

Tags: text, checkbox, vb6, textbox

Why doesn't the text inside a textbox change if the checkbox isn't ticked? If it's not checked, then the textbox's text should have "-g no", but it doesn't change when Command1 is clicked. Any solutions? Probably some very easy thing but I just haven't success with this. :\

My code:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    If Check1.Enabled = True Then
        If TextPass.Text = "" Then
            Text1.Text = "-o " & TextPool.Text & ":" & TextPort.Text & " -u " & TextUser.Text & " -g yes " & "-t " & Combo1.ListIndex
        Else
            Text1.Text = "-o " & TextPool.Text & ":" & TextPort.Text & " -u " & TextUser.Text & " -p " & TextPass.Text & " -g yes " & "-t " & Combo1.ListIndex
        End If
    Else
        If TextPass.Text = "" Then
            Text1.Text = "-o " & TextPool.Text & ":" & TextPort.Text & " -u " & TextUser.Text & " -g no " & "-t " & Combo1.ListIndex
        Else
            Text1.Text = "-o " & TextPool.Text & ":" & TextPort.Text & " -u " & TextUser.Text & " -p " & TextPass.Text & " -g no " & "-t " & Combo1.ListIndex
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Help is appreciated! Or then just fixing my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you can check or uncheck `Check1`, it is clear that it is enabled, so your condition

```
If Check1.Enabled = True Then
```

will always be true. What you actually want to do is see if `Check1` is *checked*, with the condition

```
If Check1.Value = 1 Then
```

Comment: That doesn't work. Did you test it? "Method or data member not found.". Does that Check1.Check even exists? :O

Comment: Didn't test it. That's just how I've always checked for a checkbox being checked or not. Editing my answer with a different option.

Comment: @user2404495: You should [mark the answer as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/208536) if it helped. You may also want to do that with some of your other questions like [What is the VB 6 equivalent of Process.Start?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16664872/what-is-the-vb-6-equivalent-of-process-start)

Answer (score 0):

All you had to do is change

> check1.enabled = true

.. into:

> check1.value = vbchecked

So heres the Result, (Please don't forget to rate my Answer! Thansk!)

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    If Check1.value = vbChecked Then
        If TextPass.Text = "" Then
            Text1.Text = "-o " & TextPool.Text & ":" & TextPort.Text & " -u " & TextUser.Text & " -g yes " & "-t " & Combo1.ListIndex
        Else
            Text1.Text = "-o " & TextPool.Text & ":" & TextPort.Text & " -u " & TextUser.Text & " -p " & TextPass.Text & " -g yes " & "-t " & Combo1.ListIndex
        End If
    Else
        If TextPass.Text = "" Then
            Text1.Text = "-o " & TextPool.Text & ":" & TextPort.Text & " -u " & TextUser.Text & " -g no " & "-t " & Combo1.ListIndex
        Else
            Text1.Text = "-o " & TextPool.Text & ":" & TextPort.Text & " -u " & TextUser.Text & " -p " & TextPass.Text & " -g no " & "-t " & Combo1.ListIndex
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```