# Can I Run WPF Windows called by VB6 Without Forms Interop Toolkit?

Tags: .net, wpf, vb6, com-interop, vb6-migration

We have a VB6 application we are migrating to .NET. I'm calling to .NET functions from VB6 that open up a WPF window. We often need these windows to be running on the main thread so it behaves just like another VB6 Form. We also need to run async operations from these new windows so that requires a Dispatcher and SynchronizationContext. We simply spin up a new Dispatcher and DispatcherSynchronizationContext when we first create the service that calls our WPF windows.

On one occasion, I opened a WPF window and it didn't draw its border. **Is there some possibility of threading issues I'm not aware of with the above approach? Does this seem the right way to go about this?** I'm scared there are race conditions or hidden issues to this approach since we are managing the dispatcher ourselves unlike a typical .net Application.

I know there is Interop Forms Toolkit but we don't need vb6 code to interact directly with the form so that seems like overkill and cumbersome. We're just starting to write these windows and this interface so it'd be great to know if my approach is wrong sooner rather than later.

Comment: Why did you need to create your own Dispatcher?  I'm also calling WPF from VB6 and did not need to do this. I did have to instantiate the App object manually, however.

Comment: In our case VB6 controlled the main (UI) thread. Application.Run usually sets up all the WPF stuff like the dispatcher, but that would block the VB6 thread with the message loop it starts, so instead we set up it's pieces ourselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide a COM interface (ActiveX user controls) for your WPF windows exposing .tlb and .idl files.

For this I usually create a separate project that cares only for this interface and references your WPF project.  Add there a class or few that can be instantiated by VB6 program, provide all GUIDs and interface descriptions as needed.

With this project, either use the 'Register for COM Interop' option in the project Build properties, or (my preference) use **regasm** in the project's build event scripts to create .tlb and .idl.

You deploy: your WPF DLL, .tlb, and .idl.
Then you reference this type library from your VB6 project, create and use objects as you want.

I'd suggest you manage all synchronization inside WPF and COM interface code as VB6 with COM tends to be STA.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what we are doing now. I just wanted to be sure there wasn't any odd threading issues or conflicts that could occur with this dispatcher running on the same thread as the VB6 code.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to build your WPF windows as separate processes and just call them from VB6.
Here is a thread about how to do this:
[What is the VB 6 equivalent of Process.Start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16664872/what-is-the-vb-6-equivalent-of-process-start)

Again, especially if you don't need any interaction from VB6, you should manage all threading within the WPF exe.

Answer (score 0):

Everything worked fine for me, so far. A basic example with COM visible method and event:

```cs
// COM visible interfaces
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("..."), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IWpfCtl
{
    void Show();

    void Close();

    void ComMethod(string key);
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("..."), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface IWpfCtlEvents
{
    void OnTestButton(string message);
}



// Implementation
public delegate void TestButtonDelegate(string message);

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("..."), ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IWpfCtlEvents)), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class WpfCtl : IWpfCtl, IDisposable
{
    Thread _windowThread;
    WpfWindow _wpfWindow;

    public event TestButtonDelegate OnTestButton;

    // Default parameterless constructor
    public WpfCtl()
    {
    }

    // Instantiate and show a WPF Window
    public void Show()
    {
        // create a thread  
        _windowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            // create synchronization context
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(
                new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher));

            // instantiate the window
            _wpfWindow = new WpfWindow();

            // shut down the dispatcher on window close
            _wpfWindow.Closed += (s, e) =>
                    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Background);

            // bind to window events
            _wpfWindow.testButton.Click += (sender, args) => OnTestButtonClick("Test button was clicked");

            // show the window
            _wpfWindow.Show();

            // start the dispatcher processing  
            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
        }));

        // set the apartment state  
        _windowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

        // make the thread a background thread  
        _windowThread.IsBackground = true;

        // start the thread  
        _windowThread.Start();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Close();
    }

    // Close window
    public void Close()
    {
        if (_windowThread != null && _windowThread.IsAlive && _wpfWindow != null)
        {
            if (_wpfWindow.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
                _wpfWindow.Close();
            else
            {
                _wpfWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { _wpfWindow.Close(); });
            }
        }
    }

    // COM visible method
    public void ComMethod(string key)
    {
        if (_wpfWindow != null)
            _wpfWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { _wpfWindow.Method(key); });
    }

    // COM event
    private void OnTestButtonClick(string message)
    {
        if (OnTestButton != null)
        {
            OnTestButton.Invoke(message);
        }
    }
}
```